# `E<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : invalid indexing, building a subset of an OSM Object. Edit: subset does not create a true subset

Tags: r, openstreetmap, igraph, osmar

Im trying to build a small subset of a bigger osm object:

First i load a bigger osm object into memory:

```
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(mid_point[1], mid_point[2], dist * 2, dist * 2)
src <- osmsource_osmosis(file = paste(maps_pfad,"streets_bayern.osm",sep = ""))
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)
```

then i build a subset based on coordinates of the nodes:

```
subset_bbox <- center_bbox(mid_point[1], mid_point[2], dist, dist)
```

maybe i have to use find instead of subset here?

```
muc_subset_df <- subset(muc$nodes$attrs, lon > subset_bbox[[1]] & lon < subset_bbox[[3]] 
&lat > subset_bbox[[2]] & lat < subset_bbox[[4]])

subset_ids <- muc_subset_df$id
muc_subset <- subset(muc, node_ids = subset_ids)

muc <- muc_subset
```

so basically i search for all the node ids of nodes that are in the lat&lon value range of bbox.

now i want to build n igraph of this new subset:

```
gr_muc <- as_igraph(muc)
```

And get this error:

```
E<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : invalid indexing
```

What is the mistake im making?

Before i subset i get this info regarding muc object

```
    dim(muc)
    nodes      ways relations 
   360451     59490         3
```

After Subset i get 0 ways and relations.
I think this is probably the mistake... how would i subset everything?

Even after i use `find_up` function on `subset_ids` i still dont get any `relation_ids`.

```
subset_ids <- muc_subset_df$id
osm_subset_ids <- find_up(muc, node(subset_ids))
muc_subset <- subset(muc,  osm_subset_ids)
```

What am i missing?

EDIT:
After investigating a bit further it seems that

```
muc_subset <- subset(muc,  osm_subset_ids)
```

Does not create a true subset of an osm object.
It only creates an object containing nodes but no ways or relations.
I suspect this to be a problem but still dont know how to solve it.

```
> muc_subset
osmar object
80165 nodes, 0 ways, 0 relations 
> muc
osmar object
80165 nodes, 14161 ways, 0 relations
```

Yet `osm_subset_ids` contains ids of ways.

Best regards,
Andreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say it in German: alter das wirst du nicht glauben!

So the problam was the way i called the function `subset`

It is possble (at least in my working env) to call the function `subset` with parameter `ids` and without.. probably because this function is overloaded.

this is possible:

```
muc_subset <- subset(muc,  ids = osm_subset_ids)
```

as this:

```
muc_subset <- subset(muc,  osm_subset_ids)
```

Both calls will run and produce no error.
the difference is the result:

```
osmar object
0 nodes, 0 ways, 0 relations
```

VS

```
osmar object
80165 nodes, 14161 ways, 0 relations
```

I hope it helps.
Cheers.